# How do I install the cocoapod master repo from a downloaded copy of the master repo?

Tags: terminal, installation, cocoapods

I have a slow internet connection, so I cannot use 'pod install' in my Terminal. If I did, that would attempt to download the master repo via the internet and it will time out every time (the file is large).

I downloaded the master repo from GitHub onto my iPhone, since it has a good internet connection, and used AirDrop to move the master repo file onto my computer. Is there a way to install the master repo from this file? How would I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Skip the master repo download and use the new CocoaPods CDN.

Add the following to the Podfile:

`source 'https://cdn.cocoapods.org/'`

Details in the [CocoaPods 1.7.2 blog](https://blog.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-1.7.2/).

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH @PaulBeusterien